# How to resend from Dead Letter Queue using Redis MQ?

Tags: redis, servicestack

Just spent my first few hours looking at Redis and Redis MQ.

Slowly getting the hang of Redis and was wondering how you could resend a message that is in a dead letter queue?

Also, where are the configuration options which determine how many times a message is retried before it goes into the dead letter queue?

Comment: I'm not certain about the first portion of your question, but there appears to be an optional retry count parameter on RedisMqHost.

Comment: I saw in NserviceBus that there was an executable that allowed you to retry failed messages. I suppose we would have to write something similar to this or is there functionality that retries failed entries?

Comment: @JeffMitchell The retry count is before it is sent to the dead queue

Comment: @JD. I'm looking at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10937305/353147 as a possible answer.

Comment: Thanks Chuck, I'll have a read.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, there's no way to automatically resend messages in the dead letter queue in **ServiceStack**. However, you can do this manually relatively easily:

To reload messages from the dead letter queue by using:

```
  public class AppHost {

      public override Configure(){

           // create the hostMq ...
           var hostMq = new RedisMqHost( clients, retryCount = 2 );

           // with retryCount = 2, 3 total attempts are made. 1st + 2 retries

           // before starting hostMq
           RecoverDLQMessages<TheMessage>(hostMq);

           // add handlers
           hostMq.RegisterHandler<TheMessage>( m => 
                     this.ServiceController.ExecuteMessage( m ) );

           // start hostMq
           hostMq.Start();
      }
  }
```

Which ultimately uses the following to recover (requeue) messages:

```
    private void RecoverDLQMessages<T>( RedisMqHost hostMq )
    {
        var client = hostMq.CreateMessageQueueClient();

        var errorQueue = QueueNames<T>.Dlq;
        log.Info( "Recovering Dead Messages from: {0}", errorQueue );
        var recovered = 0;

        byte[] msgBytes;
        while( (msgBytes = client.Get( errorQueue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) )) != null )
        {
            var msg = msgBytes.ToMessage<T>();
            msg.RetryAttempts = 0;
            client.Publish( msg );
            recovered++;
        }

        log.Info( "Recovered {0} from {1}", recovered, errorQueue );
    }
```

## Note

At the time of this writing, there's a possibility of **ServiceStack** losing messages. [Please See Issue 229 Here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/issues/229), so, don't kill the process while it's moving messages from the DLQ (dead letter queue) back to the input queue. Under the hood, **ServiceStack** is POPing messages from Redis.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this issue was ever resolved?  ServiceStack Issues are disabled at this time of writing, so can't follow the conversation - Thanks

Comment: No, sorry. I don't know the status of it. It's best to check the latest source code.